# $A$ is uncountable and $B$ divides $A$ in two uncountable sets. Show that $B$ is nonempty and open

Tags: real-analysis

This is the exercise 3.2.12 of *Understanding analysis 2ed.* of Abbott:

> Let $A$ be an uncountable set and let $B$ be the set of real numbers that divides $A$ into two uncountable sets; that is, $s\in B$ if both $\{x: x\in A\text { and } x< s\}$ and $\{x: x\in A \text { and } x> s\}$ are uncountable. Show that $B$ is nonempty and open.

The problem that I have here is that as I understand the problem the statement is not true, I have a counterexample:

$$A=(0,1)\cup\{2\}\cup(3,4)$$

This set is uncountable and $2\in B$ cause the condition is hold but obviously $2$ is an isolated point, so $B$ is certainly nonempty but is not open.

Maybe I dont understand something in the exercise, if Im wrong, can someone clarify the exercise? Thank you in advance.

Comment: The problem you wrote does not require $B$ to be a subset of $A$. So, for example, $2.23948092$ is in $B$.

Comment: @LeeMosher, yes, its true, I didnt see that. So the book is correct and I didnt understand it correctly. I can see now why it says "the set of real numbers", its a kind of say implicitly that $B$ is not necessarily a subset of $A$. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, we are not looking for $B \subseteq A$, we are looking for $B \subseteq \mathbb R$. In particular, for your $A$, the associated $B$ is equal to $(0, 4)$. Let us also take a moment to see how to solve the exercise (since this answer has now been accepted).

Let $S^{\uparrow}$ be the set of $s$ with $(-\infty, s) \cap A$ countable, and $S^{\downarrow}$ be the set of $s$ with $(s, \infty) \cap A$ countable. Trivially $S^{\uparrow}$ is downward closed. It cannot be all of $\mathbb R$, because then every integer would be in it, and then
$$
A = \bigcup_{n \in \mathbb Z} A \cap (-\infty, n)
$$
would be a countable union of countable sets and thus countable. Finally, it is closed, because if $(s_i)_i \in \mathbb N$ is an increasing sequence converging to $s \in S^{\uparrow}$, then
$$
A \cap (-\infty, s) = \bigcup_{i \in \mathbb N} A \cap (-\infty, s_i)
$$
is a countable union of countable sets, and thus countable. Hence $S^{\uparrow} = (-\infty, r]$ for some $r$. By the same reasoning, $S^{\downarrow} = [r', \infty)$ for some $r'$. Now we must have $r < r'$, for if $r \geq r'$ then $$A = ((-\infty, r] \cap A) \cup ([r, \infty) \cap A)$$ would be countable.

But now note that $B$ is exactly equal to $(r, r')$ by definition, so we are done.

Comment: I have a few questions: 
When you say "Let $S^{\uparrow}$ be the set of s and $A \cap (-\infty, s)$ countable" do you mean the set $S$ containing s while $A \cap (-\infty, s)$ is a separate countable set?

Comment: @Malcolm, to rephrase in more formal language, $S^\uparrow = \{s \in \mathbb R \mid A \cap (-\infty, s)\text{ is countable}\}$.

Comment: Why is $S^{\uparrow}$ downwards closed? If $x \in S^{\uparrow}$ and $y \leq x$, then why should $y \in S^{\uparrow}$?

Comment: @V.Elizabeth if y≤x, then (-inf,y) is a subset of (-inf,x), and the same for their intersections with A, hence if the latter is countable, so is the latter