# Show that an uncountable set can be separated into two disjoint uncountable subsets

Tags: real-analysis

This is a question from Steven Abbott's Understanding Analysis and I am certainly aware of how many [duplicates](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1800147/a-is-uncountable-and-b-divides-a-in-two-uncountable-sets-show-that-b-is) and [duplicates](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3042397/show-a-set-is-nonempty-and-open) there are on this website as well as the [internet](https://www.slader.com/discussion/question/let-a-be-an-uncountable-set-and-let-b-be-the-set-of-real-numbers-that-divides-a-into-two-uncountable/). However, of all the solutions, there is one essential part that still troubles me. For sake of completeness, I would show

1. The full question
2. Common solutions
3. My question

> Let A be an uncountable set and let B be the set of real number that divides A into two uncountable set; that is, $s\in$ B if both $\{x:x\in A\text{ and } x<s\}$ and $\{x:x\in A\text{ and } x>s\}$ are uncountable. Show B is nonempty and open.

The general approach to this question is

1. Prove there exists a bounded uncountable subset
2. Prove there exists a countable subset in this form $(-\infty,s)\cap A$
3. Prove B is nonempty
4. Prove B is open

Sorry for being so brief since I am stuck in point 1 and 2.Here's my confusion. Why does the following makes sense?

> Since A is a bounded uncountable set, there must exists s such that $(-\infty,s)\cap A$ is uncountable.

Of course, if it is bounded and there doesn't exist a real number, including the supremum of this set, that make the intersection uncountable, then the entire set will be countable, contradicts A is uncountable.

My question, however, is, why bounded? What is the significance behind it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It isn’t actually necessary to reduce the problem to the case in which $A$ is bounded. We can instead argue as follows.

Let

$$L=\{x\in\Bbb R:(\leftarrow,x)\cap A\text{ is countable}\}$$

and

$$R=\{x\in\Bbb R:(x,\to)\cap A\text{ is countable}\}\,.$$

- If $L\ne\varnothing\ne R$, it is straightforward to show that $B=(\sup L,\inf R)\ne\varnothing$; this is the same argument as in the bounded case.
- If $L=\varnothing=R$, then clearly $B=\Bbb R$.
- If $L=\varnothing\ne R$, then $B=(\leftarrow,\inf R)$.
- If $L\ne\varnothing=R$, then $B=(\sup L,\to)$.

Comment: Hi, Brian M. Scott, thanks for the reply. Seeing I have marked your reply as answer, the following will be a soft question that is applicable to a more general sense. When I was proving nonempty at first, I approached with contradiction, which is assuming B is empty. Hence, $\forall x\in\mathbb{R}(-\infty,x)\cap A$ is countable or $(x,\infty)\cap A$ is countable and to no avail. Since then, I didn't know how to switch my thinking simply from set B to setting 2 sets like what you have illustrated--L and R. Do you have this maturity after many practices or natural talent?

Comment: In fact, the more pressing issue is that as I step into Stephen Abbott's Understanding Analysis Chapter 3.2, my average time spent on each problem has spiked. The extent to the past chapters, such as Bolzano-Weistress theorem and future chapters such as connected set is simply too far. So, at which point should I halt and 1. look back, 2. look forward and 3.ponder deeply?

Comment: @zony_miu: I think that in my case the answer to your first question is that it’s a bit of both; I did show mathematical talent at a fairly early age, but by now I’ve also had decades of experience, and it does make a difference. I don’t think that I can answer your second question, especially since I’m not familiar with that particular book. I will say that a spike *may* be a temporary thing that subsides as you become more familiar with an area of study. Are you studying on your own? And what theory-oriented math have you previously studied?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I really shouldn't dwell on soft question since it is a bit vague. For the second question, let me refine it: suppose you know for a fact that a question has troubled you more than average, how to distinguish whether I simply don't have the tool box or I am not thinking deep enough with what I have?

Comment: Yes, I am self-studying real analysis and I will self-study pure mathematics in the future; I was once trained in linear algebra, vector calculus, discrete mathematics as well as introductory algorithm design. I was lucky enough to have good teachers and with passion I am part of top 25% percentile except vector calculus.

Comment: @zony_miu: In such cases I tend to assume that the question is simply a bit harder than average, one that really does require a bit more insight. Experience can help, since it may give you more ideas to try, but some problems are genuinely hard.