# Proving that an uncountable set can be divided into two disjoin uncountable subsets

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers

Exercise 3.2.12 from Stephen Abbott's book `Understanding Analysis` asks to prove the below statement:

> Let $\displaystyle A$ be an uncountable set and $\displaystyle B$ be the set of real numbers that divides $\displaystyle A$ into two uncountable sets; that is, $\displaystyle s\in B$ if both $\displaystyle \{x:x\in A\ \land x< s\}$ and $\displaystyle \{x:x\in A\land x >s\}$ are uncountable. Show that $\displaystyle B$ is nonempty and open.

I know that there are some extremely well-regarded [answers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4071927/show-that-an-uncountable-set-can-be-separated-into-two-disjoint-uncountable-subs) to this question. So, I don't want to make a duplicate post.

I need some help in understanding the question better itself.

For instance let $A = \mathbf{R}$ and $B = [0,1]$. Then, $(-\infty,0)$ and $(1,\infty)$ are uncountable disjoint sets, which satisfy the conditions given in the question (or so I think). So, what's wrong with this counterexample?

Comment: I don't think you get to choose $B$. It is defined as "*the* set of (*all*) real numbers that divides ...".

Comment: @user3733558, even if I were to start with two disjoint subsets of real numbers $(-\infty,0)$ and $(1,\infty)$ wouldn't that mean $B=[0,1]$?

Comment: I don't think so. With say $s=2$, I get $(-\infty,0) \cup (1,2)$ on one side and $(2,\infty)$ on the other. Aren't they both uncountable? So shouldn't $2$ also be in $B$?

Comment: I see the point, $B$ is more like a function of $A$. If $A = \mathbf{R}$, then $B$ too equals $\mathbf{R}$.